# Windows 10 IOT Foundation namespace is missing IOT

Tags: windows, cordova, iot

We are trying to add iot capabilities to our Package.appxmanifest for a cordova project. Visual studio complains that the capability we are trying to use cannot be found nor is it a child of the foundation name space.

The underlined iot:Capability shows the following when hovered over:
The element 'BackgroundTasks' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/winows10' has invalid child element 'Capabilities' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/iot/windows10'. List of possible elements expected: '...

The thing is I created this as a new project and let vs do all the work yet it cannot resolve it's own entries it's creating. We see this with both a new C# and JS project that VS generated. Can anyone help us? (Yes we added the references "Windows IoT Extensions for the UWP" 10.0.10586.0 to the project as well.). FYI We get the same error when adding  as well.

Here's the package.appxmanifest:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Package IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp iot" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10" xmlns:iot="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/iot/windows10" xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest" xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10">
    <Identity Name="com.project.syndication.sitepad" Publisher="CN=$username$" Version="2.0.0.0" />
    <mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="a885d1d0-453e-11e6-a59d-550bfa336405" PhonePublisherId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" />
    <Properties>
        <DisplayName>SitePad App</DisplayName>
        <PublisherDisplayName>ERT</PublisherDisplayName>
        <Logo>images\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
    </Properties>
    <Dependencies>
        <TargetDeviceFamily MaxVersionTested="10.0.10586.0" MinVersion="10.0.10586.0" Name="Windows.Universal" />
    </Dependencies>
    <Resources>
        <Resource Language="x-generate" />
    </Resources>
    <Applications>
        <Application Id="com.project.syndication.sitepad" StartPage="ms-appx-web:///www/index.html">
            <uap:VisualElements BackgroundColor="#464646" Description="CordovaApp" DisplayName="SitePad App" Square150x150Logo="images\Square150x150Logo.png" Square44x44Logo="images\Square44x44Logo.png">
                <uap:SplashScreen Image="images\splashscreen.png" />
                <uap:DefaultTile ShortName="SitePad App" Square310x310Logo="images\Square310x310Logo.png" Square71x71Logo="images\Square71x71Logo.png" Wide310x150Logo="images\Wide310x150Logo.png" />
            </uap:VisualElements>
            <uap:ApplicationContentUriRules>
                <uap:Rule Match="ms-appx-web:///" Type="include" WindowsRuntimeAccess="all" />
            </uap:ApplicationContentUriRules>
        </Application>
    </Applications>
    <Capabilities>
        <Capability Name="internetClient" />
        <uap:Capability Name="picturesLibrary" />
        <iot:Capability Name="systemManagement" />
    </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

Comment: Does your code compiles and runs OK?

Answer (score 0):

The hovering error looks like a bug with something(VS?), I'm seeing it multiple times, yet my code still compiles and runs OK.

No worries on this.